# UnsatisfiedLinkError when opening app in the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep getting this error whenever I open my app in the emulator:

> 05-06 18:52:13.640    2861-2861/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: scan.test, PID: 2861
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/scan.test-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libtiny-tools.so"
>               at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
>               at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
>               at android.hardware.barcode.Scanner.(Scanner.java:136)
>               at scan.test.scan_v1activity.onStart(scan_v1activity.java:97)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
>               at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: i keep getting this error whenever i open my app in the emulator

Comment: You have check ndk integration here : https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-the-ndk-with-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the exact solution but I had same issue, this is solved my issue You are missing libtiny-tools.so file in armeabi folder in libs.

if you are using android studio

[image]

add like above picture indicates.