# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-library, .so

I am making an app for QR code scanner.
Got a sample from google where everyone commented it works.
I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.iihr-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.iihr-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libiconv.so"
```

I am getting the error in this line

```
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
  }
```

the libiconv.so file is present in \libs\armeabi-v7a

as well as in

libs\armeabi

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can u try this create a **jniLibs** folder under app\src\main\ i.e. app\src\main\jniLibs put your armeabi/armeabi-v7a and x86 inside this folder and try

Comment: The message says **couldn't find "liblibiconv.so"**, it appears somewhere in your code `System.loadLibrary("libconv");` is called instead of `System.loadLibrary("conv");`

Comment: @Raghavendra didn't work :(

Comment: @Shree same error or what?

Comment: @Kai I update my question.. it was my mistake in copying the error msg

Comment: Can u tell me where exactly u kept these **.so** files I meant path?

Comment: A few more things to check: 1. is the library present in the APK? 2. Are you running on ARMv7 devices/emulators, for example x86/x64 emulators will fail if you only have ARM version of the library

Comment: @Kai \app\libs\ I have folders x89, armeabi and armeabi-v7a.. and inside these folders I have the .so files.. And I am running the app on my android mobile phone

Comment: @Shree what u have tried? u need to move these inside jniLibs folder. i.e., create a folder **jniLibs** inside main folder and move these x89, armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders into the **jniLibs** folder

Comment: I created jniLibs in src/main/ and removed from app/libs... the I ran the app but the same error came

Comment: @Shree please check the answer here is it looks like same?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074696/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-opening-app-in-the-emulator/30074815#30074815

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the error by adding more folders in jniLibs.

I added in the following fashion

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CFDa.png)

Then I put my .so files in all of them.
Still error was coming, so I changed my target sdk from 23 to 22 and it worked.